# Logic App workflow deploy in logicapp standard using CI CD pipeline

Tags: azure, devops, workflow, azure-logic-apps, cicd

I am trying to deploy a logic app workflow in logic app standard using azure devops pipeline.

I am using copy files and publish artifact task for build pipeline., but I am not sure about CD pipeline what task should be used I tried checking on internet it shows we can use function app deploy task or arm template deploy task with ARM template deploy task I am getting error though, can anyone suggest what is the right approach for performing this deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

The easiest to deploy **Logic App Standard** is to use AzureFunctionApp@1 as you mentioned in your problem. This task will create a Zip-Deploy, essentially moving all the files from the logic app folder into the fileshare that is used and extract & replace the existing files.

You did not provide any error messages that we could investigate. I found [this guide](https://azureaggregator.wordpress.com/2021/07/19/deploying-an-azure-logic-apps-standard-workflow-through-azure-devops-pipeline/) that you can follow to create a working pipeline for the Logic App you are building.

Comment: I tried using ARM template task 

but it gives me this error

2023-09-22T11:12:03.7626114Z ##[error]Error: Template file pattern matches a directory instead of a file: D:\a\r1\a\_logic_app\drop\workflow
2023-09-22T11:12:03.7727834Z ##[section]Finishing: ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope

Comment: @sjindal So the error says what is wrong? You are specifying a folder rather than a File, that is the error? Specify the workflow.json file and see if it works better :)

Comment: I tried using function app deploy task as suggested in initial comment I selected till zip file, but only connections and parameters is getting deploy but workflow is not, I can not paste the image here because of some reason, I have connections.json and parameters.json and workflow folder in root file in my repo and inside workflow folder I have workflow.json, can you suggest what could be the reason for workflow not getting deployed tried to move workflow.json to root folder also that is same folder in which connections.json and parameters.json but still workflows are not getting deployed

Comment: @sjindal In the fileshare, the workflows needs to have their own folders. For example, you have a workflow named "getCustomer"; That would be under: site/wwwroot/getCustomer/workflow.json. The connections and parameters is placed next to the workflow folders in site/wwwroot/connections.json for example.